# List of tuples to list of lists by position in tuple

Tags: python

How to make list of lists from list of tuple by position i.e.

```
list_of_tuples = [(a, 2), (b, 5), (c, 6)]
```

to

```
list_of_lists = [[a, b, c], [2, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: Simply `zip(*list_of_tuples)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use zip, and then map:

```
list_of_tuples = [(a, 2), (b, 5), (c, 6)]

new_list = zip(*list_of_tuples)

final_list = map(list, new_list)

print final_list
```

Edit:

As @PM 2Ring pointed out, in python 3, map returns an iterator, so it needs to be passed to list, if you really want a list:

```
final_list = list(map(list, new_list))
```

Comment: Note that in Python 3 both `zip` and `map` return iterators, not lists, so you'd need to wrap that `map` call in `list()` if you really need a list. Or use a list comp, eg in Python 3.6+ `[*map(list, zip(*list_of_tuples))]`

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I was not sure what version of Python the OP was using, so I used Python 2. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: Not a problem. FWIW, the [SO Python Community](http://sopython.com) policy is that we assume generic questions to be Python 3, unless the question is tagged Python 2, or is using obvious Python 2 syntax. And even then we try to give answers that are applicable to both versions. Python 2 will reach its End Of Life in 2020, so we're trying to encourage people to migrate to Python 3, and to discourage newbies from starting with Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3+, map function returns map object. Therefore you have to convert map object to list by using: `list(map_object).`
Here all code:

```
list_of_tuples = [('a', 2), ('b', 5), ('c', 6)]
zipped_list = zip(*list_of_tuples)
list_of_lists = list(map(list, zipped_list))
print(list_of_lists)
```